# If someone's so lazy they use an auto-generated username, they may not have done email verification. What are the chances that they'll ever return?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, new-users, email, unregistered-users

New visitors to Stack Exchange can post questions or answers as a guest.  The site asks them to specify their name and their email address.  If they're lazy and they leave the "name" field blank, the site will auto-generate a display name for them, such as "user9276583".

Email verification is a separate step.  They must take additional actions in order to get an verification email sent to them.  Then they must open the email and click the link.

If a guest is so lazy that they didn't specify a display name, I think it's reasonable for me to fear that they might also have been so lazy that they never completed email verification.  Still, I might be tempted to ask in a comment in order to seek clarification of their tech-support question.

In practice, if a user is 100% brand-new to the Stack Exchange network, and if they have an auto-generated display name, what are the chances that they'll ever be back again to respond to my comment?

Comment: Are you also afraid of unregistered users?

Comment: @Andy: I'm not sure. If they're unregistered, might they still have done email verification?

Comment: Interesting that you equate someone not providing a custom user name with being lazy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The chances they'll ever return are irrelevant if their question is answerable. You get at most one upvote and an accept from the OP. You can get scores of upvotes from other people. Yes, an autogenerated id might indicate a drive-by user who will not reply to your comments. But it might not. Let me suggest the following workflow:

- is the question answerable as written, and without a good answer yet? **Answer it**. We exist as much to help the next person with this question as the asker
- is the question unanswerable, but just missing one piece of info? **Comment** - perhaps the asker will return, even though they are less likely than some to do so, but more importantly others will see what is needed to get an answer
- is the question unsalvageable without a lot of help from the asker? Flag or vote to close, and comment explaining why. If the asker returns and fixes their question, fine, and if not you are leaving explanations for those who read it later

Knowing the chances of the user returning really doesn't change this workflow. Whether it's a 1% chance or a 99% chance, these are the right things to do.

Answer (score 9):

> If a guest is so lazy that they didn't specify a display name

So you assume that someone who is not using their real name is lazy. I would like to see some facts to support that...

Some users just don't like to have their name in public. They don't want to be remembered in 20 years of that stupid question they've asked on Stack Overflow, or any other site. *That* is why users are free to pick their own name, and also to use an auto-generated name. It has nothing to do with laziness, nor the number of times they will return.

So *what are the chances that they'll ever be back again to respond to my comment*? just as much as anyone else.

Comment: They still can make up a pseudonym, like "unforgettableid". That's not so much work to do. If the site offers you a "display name" field and encourages you to fill it in, it's a kind deed to at least write _something_ there.

Comment: Well, that is your opinion. I am sure not everyone shares that need to fill in that field.

Comment: I still stand by my opinion, but I now see — based on your answer, plus based on the voting here — that I should take a gentler approach. I have posted [a new question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281260/i-have-a-perhaps-irrational-fear-that-brand-new-users-with-auto-generated-user) to see what people think of my proposed new gentler approach.