# I have a (perhaps irrational) fear that brand-new users with auto-generated usernames may not return. Can I encourage them to change their username?

Tags: discussion, comments, new-users, display-names, unregistered-users

New visitors to Stack Exchange can post questions or answers as a guest. The site asks them to specify their name and their email address. If they're lazy and they leave the "name" field blank, the site will auto-generate a display name for them, such as "user9276583".

Email verification is a separate step. They must take additional actions in order to get an verification email sent to them. Then they must open the email and click the link.

If a guest didn't bother specifying a display name, I may fear **(perhaps irrationally)** that they might also have never completed email verification. Still, I might want to comment and to seek clarification of their tech-support question.

In practice, if a user is 100% brand-new to the Stack Exchange network, and if they have an auto-generated display name, can I welcome them sort of like they do on [one specific Stack Exchange website](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190/welcoming-new-users), by posting two separate comments?

1. `Welcome to Stack Exchange, and thanks for your question! We hope you'll like the place and decide to stay. I suggest that you [edit your profile](//unix.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) and give yourself a nicer pseudonym!`
2. `What version of Unix are you using? Please [edit] your question and tell us!`

<sub>(I thank Isaac Moses for posting [a post elsewhere](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190/welcoming-new-users) which helped to inspire this one.)</sub>

Comment: What makes you think that changing a display name would make someone more or less prone to returning?

Comment: @Oded: I don't think that changing their display name would make them more prone to returning. But I do fear that, if they didn't bother choosing a display name, maybe they never bothered with email verification either. Like I said, maybe my fear is irrational.

Comment: Why would you care about email verification?

Comment: I agree that an autogenerated user is statistically unlikely to be a returning visitor. The best you can do maximize the chances that the user actually comes back, is to give him/her an awesome good quality answer.

Comment: I just think you are making a broad assumption here. I have no idea if there is such a correlation and even if there is - that something should be done about it.

Comment: @aloobe: But if they're unlikely to return even one time, how will they see my awesome good quality answer?

Comment: I agree with Oded here. First we need to have proof this is actually a problem. Only then we can talk about changing or forcing anything. And even then, forcing them to pick a name doesn't make them return.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: I agree that _encouraging_ them to pick a name won't make them any more likely to return. Still, if they do pick a name, then at least the next time they return (if they ever return) they won't look like drive-by guests anymore.

Comment: Related: http://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/220/78

Answer (score 8):

You can welcome them like that, but you shouldn't. Their display name is [their personal choice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281258/245360). Focus on their post, not their display name.

Don't force your opinion to them. I don't see the point in asking this at all. If there is something bad about using default display names, SE shouldn't allow it. But it isn't a problem, so why bother?

Comment: Why is it customary/accepted on Mi Yodeya to encourage them to change their display name?

Comment: You should ask that on their meta. I find that an interesting question but I can't answer that. I don't know any community that asks that from their users...

Comment: You mean any _other_ community, right?

Comment: I don't know MY, so my comment was correct from my point-of-view.

Comment: I thought more about the matter.  Perhaps changing their display name is not for their benefit, but for **our** benefit.  It allows us to distinguish them in our minds from the many other users with very similar generic display names, which differ only by their numerical suffix.